Invalid dart suggestions
I have got extensions on List
extension CustomListExtensions<TType> on List<TType> {
  List<TOther> transform<TOther>(TOther Function(TType) fn) {
   ....
  }
}

I have used this all over application which was working fine.
But now, I am seeing all duplicate code suggestions (intelllisense) in vscode. Tried in Android Studio and I see the same issue.
It is suggesting every file this extension was used as you could see in the screenshot.

My current environment
Flutter 3.24.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 4cf269e36d (5 days ago) • 2024-09-03 14:30:00 -0700
Engine • revision a6bd3f1de1
Tools • Dart 3.5.2 • DevTools 2.37.2

Anyone else has seen this issue please?

And where is Column(children: [1, 2, 3].tran) coming from?  If the code is actually using .tran, then that seems like a legitimate error.  Is that from the body of your extension?  It's hard to give you specific help when you've posted only a screenshot and haven't provided more details or a means to reproduce the problem.

@jamesdlin That is a temp code to show the issue.

@jamesdlin, OP's code is not the problem. Yes @ramtheconqueror, Dart VS Code extension is suggesting duplicate completions for me on generics as well. It suggests an import completion on an extension method for every file I imported that extension into in my project. Dart-Code issues #3555 and #3679 are closed but still not fixed, e.g. ```extension LetExtension on T {
R let(R Function(T) op) => op(this);
}


There, I've opened a new issue: https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/5254

This was a bug in the Dart analysis server that has recently been fixed. Extensions were incorrectly being shown for each file that imported them, rather than only files that exported/declared them.

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/56320
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/commit/a0411ae24485526470b7f99148132f29fe01edcb

The fix will ship in a future Dart/Flutter SDK release.
